# Excel Page Break Macro

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to append a macro to fix an issue that has come up due to changes in how the worksheet is exported. I want the line of code to select just the sheet named invoice, remove all page breaks, then look for the cell with "grand Total" and place a page break 1 row beneath it.

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Invoice" Then
    ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
End If

If Range(A, H).FormulaR1C1 = "Grand Total" Then
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Cell.Offset(1, 0)
End If
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that will cause the code not to perform as desired.

**1)** Work directly with the "Invoice" sheet, which eliminates the need for `ActiveSheet` and the `IF` block.

```
With Worksheets("Invoice")
    .ResetAllPageBreaks
```

**2)** Use the `Find` function to look for text in a cell.

```
    Dim grandTotal as Range
    Set grandTotal = .Range("A:H").Find("Grand Total", lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not grandTotal is Nothing Then 'make sure you found it
        .HPageBreaks.Add grandTotal.Offset(1)
    End If

 End With
```

Comment: Work much better thank you. It is still doing some kinda of break with the dotted line. I am not sure what this is called and how to remove it. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SEN7P_hmR7z2lmOB9KZz0WICvkH5aLt5